# Interacting with the data point - flot

Tags: javascript, graph, flot

I'm using this site as a reference: http://astro.unl.edu/naap/hr/animations/hrExplorer.html

I need to add a pointer "x" as the link and manipulate slide the pointer should move the x and y axis.

See my code: http://jsfiddle.net/2Xn9f/4/

Understand?

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you want a cross.  In the flot [API](http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt), it actually gives us that function!

```
function cross(ctx, x, y, radius, shadow) {
    var size = radius * Math.sqrt(Math.PI) / 2;
    ctx.moveTo(x - size, y - size);
    ctx.lineTo(x + size, y + size);
    ctx.moveTo(x - size, y + size);
    ctx.lineTo(x + size, y - size);
}
```

So that part is easy enough.  Then, if you want to be able to slide it around the graph, you can create some [jQuery UI sliders](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#steps) that control x and y, and have it replot every time a slider is moved:

```
$('#xslide').slider({
    value: 1,
    min: 0,
    max: 2,
    step: 0.1,
    slide: function(e, ui) {
        plotSlide([[ui.value, $('#yslide').slider('value')]]);
    }
});
```

Where plotSlide does something like this:

```
function plotSlide(data2) {
    $.plot($("#chart1"), [{
        data: data1},
    {
        data: data2,
        color: 'red',
        points: {
            show: true,
            symbol: cross
        },
        lines: {
            show: false
        }
    }], 
    options1);
}
```

See it in action here:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/2Xn9f/5/

Comment: Well....I already have the sliders. See my code: http://jsfiddle.net/tmDpZ/9/

But I'm not able to add a cross

Comment: So, when i try add the part of the sliders that control x and y, the graph and across ....the sliders disappears

Comment: See this links: http://astro.unl.edu/naap/hr/animations/hrExplorer.html

It has animation between sun and star using sliders. Beside it displays a graph, so when i control the slide temperature or luminosity the across is moved in x-axis or y-axis. Understand?

Comment: Right, but your question here was about the graph itself, which I don't see in your jsfiddle.

Comment: Yeah, but the two jsfiddle are related. This: http://jsfiddle.net/tmDpZ/9/ that has the sliders and this: http://jsfiddle.net/2Xn9f/6/ that has the graph.